# Blur exception based on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout

[image]

**How it works**

I am building a demo search box where the search results show up when the input field is not empty while focusing in. When you blur the search results container hides.

**Problem**

The problem appears when I click the search results container. The input field blurs with the result that the search results container hides.

How to make it work so that the search results container does not hide when clicking it (or an element inside it).

**HTML**

```
<div class="searchbox">
   <input class="input">
   <div class="search-results">
      // Results
   </div>
</div><!--End .searchbox-->
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.searchfield .input').focusin(function() {

   // When value is not empty show search results
   if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $('.searchbox .search-results').fadeIn(10);
   }

   // Other code

}).focusout(function() {

   // Hide search results
   $('.searchbox .search-results').fadeOut(10);

   // Other code

});
```

Comment: Input has no child elements, so `focus`. (Instead of `focusin`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks, changed. But that does not fix the problem, right?

Comment: No, it's not a solution to your issue, it's just a *comment*, *tip-of-the-day* :).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding a delay on the fadeout during the blur. This way I was able to click the button inside the container.

```
$('.searchfield .input').focusin(function() {

   // When value is not empty show search results
   if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $('.searchbox .search-results').fadeIn(10);
   }

   // Other code

}).focusout(function() {

   // Hide search results
   $('.searchbox .search-results').delay(300).fadeOut(10);

   // Other code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need JS / jQuery.
Try with `required` attribute and CSS's `:valid` to achieve the desired

```css
.searchbox {
  position: relative;
}

.searchbox .search-results {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.searchbox .input:valid + .search-results {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
  <input class="input" required>
  <div class="search-results">
    <p>Register to use this feature</p>
    <button>JOIN NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

If you prefer jQuery instead:

```js
$(".input").on({
  "input focus": function() {
    $(this).closest(".searchbox").toggleClass("showInfo", !!$.trim(this.value));
  },
  "blur": function() {
    $(this).closest(".searchbox").removeClass("showInfo");
  }
});
```

```css
.searchbox {
  position: relative;
}

.searchbox .search-results {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.search-results:hover,
.searchbox.showInfo .search-results {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
  <input class="input">
  <div class="search-results">
    <p>Register to use this feature</p>
    <button>JOIN NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Might not seem obvious at first, but the `:hover` helps to keep the element visible when interacting with it's content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need a jQuery solution, because I have other cpde that runs during this process.

Comment: @Robbert added an example.